# Is there a way to classify all finite groups with trivial centre?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a way to classify all finite groups with trivial centre?

As far as I know, all finite symmetric groups, all non-abelian finite simple groups, $A_4$, the trivial group, and all direct products of aforementioned groups satisfy that condition.

But are there any other ones?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: direct products of any of these.

Comment: $A_4$ is not in your list.

Comment: All (nontrivial) semidirect products with faithful actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a classification would include all
*solvable* non-nilpotent groups with trivial center. It is well known,
that this is "in some sense impossible", e.g., see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180355/in-what-sense-is-the-classification-of-all-finite-groups-impossible).